# Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharpCore, Version=1.3.40.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, pdfsharp

I am using PdfSharpCore version 1.3.40 in a MVC ASP.Net netcoreapp2.1 and it works perfectly on my windows localhost, but when I publish it on a server Linux running Apache the follow exception occurs:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'PdfSharpCore, Version=1.3.40.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo                                                               ken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I already checked that the PdfSharpCore dll is there, but the system couldn't find it.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Where is this dll file located? Please make sure the dll name  'PdfSharpCore' with version '1.3.40.0' in your ASP.NET Core application root Bin folder or GAC in server. And make sure its dependences are all available on server.

Comment: We managed to solve the problem, we were forgetting to replace the .deps.json file that contains the dependencies with the new PdfSharpCore.dll dll included in the project. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve the problem, we were forgetting to replace the .deps.json file that contains the dependencies with the new PdfSharpCore.dll dll included in the project. Solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).